# Integration between alfresco and spring-data

Tags: spring-data, alfresco

We would like to create alfresco AMP module, which will use spring-data to connect to external database. Is it possible to create such module?

Thank you

Comment: Sure, why not??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by providing database properties in alfresco-global.properties

```
   db.driver: The fully-qualified name of the JDBC driver class
    db.url: The JDBC URL to the database connection
    db.username: The name used to authenticate with the database
    db.password: The password used to authenticate with the database
```

and configure your database with required settings
Refer this [doc link](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5770-database-configuration) for more information

Comment: Actually, I have to create a Java class that has to retrieve data from external database but Alfresco should still operate in its own database.
I think that using  alfresco-global.properties is going to configure Alfresco to switch to another database

Comment: @user2021886 Did you succeed ? I try to connect a second database without success